# Issue with handling boolean instance in Flutter class

Tags: flutter, boolean

In my flutter app I have a class and a list of classes like the following:

```
class GuestType {
  final String name;
  bool isActive;

  GuestType({this.name, this.isActive});
}

List<GuestType> _guestTypes = [
  GuestType(name: 'White', isActive: false),
  GuestType(name: 'Blue', isActive: false),
  GuestType(name: 'Lavander', isActive: false),
  GuestType(name: 'Green', isActive: false),
  GuestType(name: 'Pink', isActive: false),
  GuestType(name: 'Yellow', isActive: false)
];
```

I'm mapping through _guestTypes and creating a card containing the name instance.
Each card has the onPress attribute and what I need to achieve is that when a card is pressed, the isActive instance is set to true. However, only one card can be true at any time, so when a card is pressed all the other cards must be set to false.

This is my code to achieve the desired result:

```
...
children: _guestTypes
                      .map(
                        (type) => Card(
                          colour: type.isActive == true
                              ? widgetAttivo
                              : widgetInattivo,
                          onPress: () {
                             setState(() {
                               _guestTypes
                                   .map((guest) => guest.isActive == true
                                       ? setState(() {
                                           guest.isActive = false;
                                           type.isActive = !type.isActive;
                                         })
                                       : setState(() {
                                           type.isActive = !type.isActive;
                                         }));
                             });
                     
                            
                          },
...
```

This code doesn't work, I can still select and activate multiple cards.

Any clue?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong tool for the job. `map` is a way to create a new iterable, by mapping each item to a new item. That is not what you want. You simply want to iterate the existing items. That has always been a job for a *loop*:

```
onPress: () {
  setState(() {
    for(var guest in _guestTypes) {
      guest.isActive = false;
      type.isActive = !type.isActive;
    }
  }
}
```

I also shortened your loop body. It does the same thing, but with half the code.

Comment: Thank you! I used for loop as you suggested, but I took type.isActive = !type.isActive out of it . It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

In your `setState` call, you are re-mapping `_guestTypes`, but are not doing anything with the return value. `map()` does not map in-place, it returns an updated map.

Also, you don't need to use `setState` both inside and outside the map function, only setting it around the content you want to update is enough (and better).

```dart
() {
    setState(() {
        // notice the change here - use the result and set the value in the state
        _guestTypes = _guestTypes
            .map((guest) { 
                    // set `true` for same guest type, `false` for others. 
                    // (use a different condition to compare them if that isn't good enough)
                    guest.isActive = type.name == guest.name; 

                    // needs to return the final value for each item
                    return guest;
            }).toList();
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map` and changing some attributes inside the callback will not affect you current list (This is why map returns `Iterable`).
So as a solution I will propose the following :

```
setState(() {
_guestTypes = _guestTypes.map((guest) {
  if(guest.name == type.name){
    guest.isActive = true;
  }else{
    guest.isActive = false;
  }
  return guest;
 }).toList();
});
```

You have to check if the selected item name is the same with the item in the map. make it isActive true and all the others false.